# Switching module based on url zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have two domain name **www.example1.com** and **www.example2.com**.

my website is in ZEND Framework

I am pointing this two domain in to same folder now I want to switch module according to the url name

ie: if the domain is **www.example1.com** then the module should be **module1** and 
if the domain is **www.example2.com** then the module should be **module2**

any help will be really appreciated.